# Was the 2017 NHS attack targeted?

Tags: virus, ransomware

The news has been alive with the HNS ransomware story this weekend (13th May 2017) and the coverage has been loose guesswork at best generally.

So what I'm trying to figure out is: Was this actually a targeted attack?, or simply a matter of someone opening a random spam mail (for example) and the infection spreading internally from there?

You'd think the NHS would know a thing or 2 about "infection control"..........!

Comment: It's hit many other companies, too, so I'd guess not. Health care industry is an easy target because of delayed patching though.

Comment: Basically all the articles state that many different companies in many different sectors and countries have been impacted. So no

Comment: "You'd think the NHS would know a thing or 2 about "infection control"..........!" <== On what basis do you assert this ? Like they have more budget than private companies ? :) (the pun is good tho)

Comment: no basis, PURELY a pun :-D (Awaits "Information security is no joke" from Buzz Killington...)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is:No.

It was absolutely not targeted because of the use of the remote code execution vulnerability used in EternalBlue (leaked from NSA hack)  to spread the malware , they probably scanned the entire internet for vulnerable systems with exposed 445/tcp port (allowing the exploit of the SMB - an application-layer network protocol mainly used for providing shared access to files)

Comment: I don't see how the use of EternalBlue means that the initial infection was not targeted. WannaCry uses multiple attack vectors, including phishing emails. Both the phishing emails and the EternalBlue exploit could still be originally targeted at the NHS.

Comment: @Sjoerd NHS is a collateral damage you do not need to be einstein to know that all infections where not targeted. I know It because I watched in real time the very first infections peak. So do you really think that FedEX, Spain telecommunications company Telefonica, Portugal Telecom, In Germany, railway operator Deutsche Bahn...and dozen of high profit companies where targeted AND fooled exactly at the same time ?

Comment: @Sjoerd This made me think of you https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2017/05/how-did-wannacry-ransomworm-spread/